# Python two return values with recursion

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how I can return multiple values from a function. I've tried and searched for information and it seems I should be using tuples.

Here's a normal recursive function (copied from another stackoverflow question):

```
def backward(text):
    if text == '':
        return text
    else:
        return text[-1] + backward(text[:-1])
```

Now, let's say I want the function to return both the reversed text but also the initial text in a tuple. How would I make it work?
What I am trying to get:

```
>>> print(backward('hello'))
('olleh','hello')
```

Keep getting errors like "Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly". Got any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: just `return first_thing,second_thing`

Comment: Return a tuple or a dict if you have the need for doing it. SO where is your problem?

Comment: Also, your snippet is fine, please post the code you're getting errors for.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need recursion for this

```
def backward(text):
    if text == '':
        return text
    else:
        return text[::-1], text
```

Comment: @user2005203 - if this is homework, you should mention that it's homework and explain what the actual assignment is. [stackoverflow homework policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

```
def backward(text):
    return (backwardImpl(text), text)

def backwardImpl(text):
    if text == '':
        return text
    else:
        return text[-1] + backwardImpl(text[:-1])
```

```
>>> print(backward('hello'))
('olleh','hello')
```

Version with one function:

```
def backward(text, recursiveCall = False):
    if not recursiveCall:
        return (backward(text, True), text)

    if text == '':
        return text
    else:
        return text[-1] + backward(text[:-1], True)
```

However if client calls with second argument set to `True` it will spoil the result.

Comment: Both of your functions are named `backward`.

Comment: Took me some time to understand the last row, but I think I got it now! By the way: is it possible to do this with only one function?

Comment: @user2005203 Try this, it's much better.

Comment: @user2005203 Yes, using an optional parameter. But it gives possibility to call the function incorrectly, and get wrong result.